# Как перевернуть SQL-запрос? После применения DESC и LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Организовал запрос:

```
SELECT
  `num_rec`,
  `user_id`,
  `question`,
  `user_answer`,
  `right_answer`
FROM `user_answer`
WHERE `user_id` = 123
ORDER BY `num_rec` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Логика запроса: выбрать последние 10 записей созданных определённым юзером.
Это для печати отчёта. Но вот в чём соль. Эту выборку надо теперь как-то перевернуть. Что-бы записи шли по возрастающей.
Если убрать конструкцию `` ORDER BY `num_rec` DESC ``, то естественно попадут первые записи этого юзера, а нужны 10 его последних записей в правильной последовательности.

Comment: а если получившийся запрос обернуть в другой, в котором отсортировать так как необходимо?

Comment: @Bald Как-то чудом наткнулся на запросы в запросы, и уже реализовал, но там одно непонятное место - буква `a` без почему-то неё не работает. Не подскажите, что это она обозначает?
``SELECT * FROM (тут первый запрос) a ORDER BY `num_rec` ASC``
Вот перед `ORDER BY`, что за `a`?

Comment: Не понял, вам же ответ написали с конкретным примером. Что не так?!

Comment: @Bald, я понимаю, но решение я нашёл сам, немного чуть ранее, чем дали ответ здесь. И ещё второе - хочу всё знать.

Comment: а в вашем случае является алиасом

Comment: @Bald - Спасибо. Прочитал позже разъяснение от Anton Shchyrov.

Comment: Прочитайте в инете про алиасы: они могут устанавливаться на таблицу, колонку таблицы, результат запроса как у вас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать подзапрос

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT `num_rec`,
    `user_id`,
    `question`,
    `user_answer`,
    `right_answer`
  FROM
    `user_answer`
  WHERE
    `user_id` = 123
  ORDER BY
    `num_rec` DESC
  LIMIT 10
) sub
ORDER BY
  sub.`num_rec`
```

Comment: в интернете на каком-то ресурсе нашёл такое решение:
``SELECT * FROM (тут первый запрос) a ORDER BY `num_rec` ASC``.
Вместо `a` подставлял любой символ, даже кириллицу и оно работает! Что это такое? Почему оно так себя ведёт?

Comment: @I_CaR Выбирать данные можно только из таблицы, а каждая таблица должна иметь имя. Кода мы пишем `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)` мы внутренним селектом создаем временную таблицу и из нее уже выбираем данные. Но получается, что эта временная таблица не имеет имени. Поэтому мы указываем для нее алиас `) sub`

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Что-то я как-то совсем забывать стал SQL. Ведь знал про алиасы. Просто редко их использовал.